# pyspark dates are offset

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large (5B rows) of timeseries data, as separate segment parquet files in a directory. If I read each parquet file separately using pandas `read_parquet(engine="fastparquet")` then I can see the correct data. For instance price on day `2022-08-01` is `150.98`:

| Date | Price |
| --- | --- |
| `2022-08-01` | `150.98` |

However, if I read the same data via pyspark, I get the incorrect data for that date. It seems to be offset by one day

| Date | Price |
| --- | --- |
| `2022-08-01` | `153.37` |

The value `153.37` is in fact the price on `2022-08-02`.

My code is as follows:

```
sc = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("test") \
    .master('local[*]') \
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "200") \
    .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize","5g") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory","40g") \
    .config("spark.driver.memory","10g") \
    .config("spark.rdd.compress", "true") \
    .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true") \
    .getOrCreate()

df   = sc.read\
         .option("primitivesAsString","true")\
         .option("allowNumericLeadingZeros","true")\
         .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd")\
         .parquet(f'{data_rroot}/*.parquet')
```

The strange thing is that the dates at this stage of the ingestion are `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` format, even though I've set the `timestampFormat` option to be `yyyy-MM-dd` (loading the same data via pandas read_parquet behaves correctly). pyspark reads dates using java's `SimpleDateFormat` class. To fix this problem I then do:

```
df = df.withColumn('Date', F.to_date(df["Date"],'yyy-MM-dd'))
```

I have tried setting the option `.config ("spark.sql.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInRead", "CORRECTED")` but that hasnt worked either.

I am trumped, and do not understand what is going on. Even chatGPT cant help :)

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. The problem was timezone. Problem goes away with this addition

```
.config("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
```

thank you for your time.